# Need an idea how to count this

Tags: combinatorics

Jessica have two necklaces, both with 100 white and 100 black beads. She wants to lay the first necklace onto the the second one, so that she gets as many beads, matched by color, as possible. She can rotate and reflect the first necklace. How many matching beads can she be sure to obtain, independently on the initial order of the beads?

Comment: The average number of matched beads, over all rotations and reflections is $100$, so you can get at least $100$ matches. I think I can see an example of a pair which will never give you more than $100$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Thank you! Turns out we can use only rotations...